# Einstein Analytics scheduled email

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, conga-composer

Is it possible to have a scheduled email of a dashboard in .pdf format from Einstein analytics?

Setting notification is not possible because it only send the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet a functionality in Einstein analytics. You can Up vote this idea:-

1. [Ability to Send Wave Dashboard as a scheduled dashboard in email to public group](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TrSFQA0)
2. [Schedule emailing of WAVE dashboard snap shots](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LjgrQAC)

Note:- Yet, Their is not comment from salesforce on this.

Comment: Thanks @sanket, I read about conga but no links to connect to Einstein analytics I;m still searching ..

Comment: I did not get what you are telling?